# No packages found with specified pattern

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Deploy azure app service to slot build step in Team Services, I want to be able to build my solution with PackageAsSingleFile set to False. However when I try to release the package with path to the artifact created I get "No packages found with specified pattern".

Do I need to create two artifacts, one as zip file and one as a package of files to be able to do what I want? I have tried different path to folders, but I get same error no matter.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer to these steps:

1. NuGet Installer task to restore package
2. Visual Studio Build task (Solution: ***.sln; Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio 2015; MSBuild Arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"; Platform: $(BuildPlatform); Configuration: $(BuildConfiguration))
3. Publish Build Artifacts (Path to Publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory); Artifact Name: drop; Artifact Type: Server)
4. Edit/create Release definition
5. Link artifact to previous build
6. Azure App Service Deploy (Package or Folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/drop)
7. Uncheck **Publish using Web Deploy option**

Answer (score 3):

I used zip file, and Azure App Services Deploy task can be execute successfully.

For the related build definition, you can use below tasks:

**Copy Files task:**

Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

Contents: the project you want to deploy to Azure, such as A`SPNETCoreProj\**`.

Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

**Archive Files task:**
Root folder (or file) to archive: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.
Archive type: `zip`.
Archive file to create: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/project.zip`.

**Publish Build Artifacts task:**

Path to Publish: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

Artifact Name: `drop`.

In the release definition, you can specify **Package or folder** as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip` in **Azure App Services Deploy task**.