# VSTS Release task can't find the zip file

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to implement the CI/CD process for my ASP.NET website. I have the build definition and release definition set up like this:
[image: build definition]
[image: release definition]

But when I queue a new build, the release task complained "Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip". I think this is because the zip file path in release definition is wrong. What should I do to make the build task and release task play together?

Comment: see if this discussion helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803475/no-packages-found-with-specified-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Archive task is after your Publish Artifacts task, so the zip file isn't included in the artifacts published by your build.