# Error: No package found with specified pattern

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

I have tried to push the image repo to IIS server. i have set the image folder in path to publish in publish Artifact. The build pipelines run sucessfully without any issues. But in release pipeline, got a error **"2022-01-03T05:02:47.5647566Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern.
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job."**
Here i have attached the build artifact images and release pipelines images.
Plese let me know the solution for this issue.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Would you please share the full debug log for the release pipeline? So that we could check it.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages. Post the actual error messages. Your screenshots are unreadable.

Answer (score -2):

I've been through this, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117244/azure-devops-pipeline-release-error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d)

Builds section and edit it.

At the very end of the .yaml file you need to add an additional line.

> - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

Comment: This does not answer the question. They are clearly not using YAML pipelines.